# TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable when checking for nonetype

Tags: pandas, dataframe, nonetype

I am trying to detect Nonetype in a single cell of a 1 column, 15 row dataframe with the following:

```
if str(row.iloc[13][:]) is None:
     print("YES")
```

But this causes the error: TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Comment: Why not `if row.iloc[13] is None:` ? Also can you explain more, what need?

Comment: do you mean `if row.iloc[13] is None:`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `row` is `Series`, then if select value by position:

```
row.iloc[13]
```

output is scalar. So cannot slice scalar value by `[:]`. Also if convert to string by `str` cannot compare by `None`, but by string like:

```
if str(row.iloc[13]) == 'None':
```

If want compare by `None`:

```
if row.iloc[13] is None:
```

Or if compare by `NaN` or `None`:

```
if pd.isna(row.iloc[13]):
```